# User-friendly links behavior without mod_rewrite

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

I want to make user-friendly links (eg :  http://www.website.com/post-id/this-is-post-title) but when a user tap "http://www.website.com/post-id/changed-post-title-by-user" the address should be replaced - instantly and without redirection -to "http://www.website.com/post-id/post-title" where "post-title" is a the title of a the post with ID equal to "post-id" just like StackOverFlow links behave. I Know the Push History State API :

```
history.pushState(state, title [, url])
```

but this method require Javascript to be enabled and some websites like StackOverFlow method works with JS disabled.
I handle links in "index.php" like that:

```
$requestURI = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$command = array_values($requestURI);

if(condition)
{
  include('page.php');
}
```

Comment: In essence, what you’re saying is that you want redirection without using redirection. Good luck with that... The only way to change the url showing in the browser is to redirect or manipulate it directly with push state. FWIW, redirection is how friendly urls work.

Comment: @TimMorton take the link of my question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451745/user-friendly-links-behavior-without-mod-rewrite" you can change the last part "user-friendly-links-behavior-without-mod-rewrite" to whatever you want and the link will be changed to current link instantly without redirection even though you disable javascript which push state is based on.

Comment: I keep trying to figure out what mechanism you’re talking about: what changes the link, on what event? are you saying that when you type in url a, it comes up as url b after you press enter?

Comment: @TimMorton this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451745/whatever"  will show the correct post but the address bar will show this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451745/user-friendly-links-behavior-without-mod-rewrite"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are observing is a server redirect in action.  When you type

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451745/whatever
```

The server receives that request and issues a `301` status code (Moved Permanently redirect)

```
Request URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451745/whatever
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301  (from disk cache)
```

The location of the redirect is `/questions/65451745/user-friendly-links-behavior-without-mod-rewrite` as seen in the response headers below:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: private
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com
date: Sat, 26 Dec 2020 02:50:42 GMT
feature-policy: microphone 'none'; speaker 'none'
location: /questions/65451745/user-friendly-links-behavior-without-mod-rewrite
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
vary: Fastly-SSL
via: 1.1 varnish
x-account-id: 2441033
x-aspnet-duration-ms: 1
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
x-flags: AA
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-is-crawler: 0
x-providence-cookie: 372ce5a1-ff98-0aae-7962-a68742f9dfee
x-request-guid: f5cc8c0f-2ac7-427c-8f1f-aa007566d70f
x-route-name: Questions/Show
x-served-by: cache-mdw17325-MDW
x-sql-count: 2
x-sql-duration-ms: 1
x-timer: S1608951042.245905,VS0,VE26
```

Long story short, if you want a url to be changed "in flight", redirection is the only way to do it. And it's not done in php nor html; it's a server feature.

Comment: It’s been a long time since I’ve set that up in apache. Best I can do is point you in the right direction. The key is [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/).

Comment: Even with mod_rewrite , how can the server (Apache or IIS) redirect to a link with the correct post title (the last part of the link)? that require a database connection !

Comment: One possible scenario: All requests routed through index.php which parses the url (mod rewrite possibly adds path as a query string), validates, looks up the value for last part of link if invalid, and issues 301 redirect to the correct address. If correct address, it simply routes to the proper controller, model, and view. (or for non mvc, includes the proper script)

Comment: I use this method as you can see in my question but without mod_rewrite, checking if the post title is correct is resources consuming process and it seems to be slow. and I think StackOverFlow and other websites do not use this approach.

Comment: As you pointed out, they have to hit the database to get the title. One database call is not a big deal at all; look up the concept of url slugs. If the provided slug != the lookup slug, redirect to the looked up slug. If they match, load up the matching controller etc.